# COPY command fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Been stuck on this for the last 3 days. I'm building an image in a docker and
copy command fails due to not finding the right directory.

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD python3 manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

which is run by this docker-dev file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
  volumes:
    - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
  ports:
    - 5001:5000
  environment:
    - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
    - FLASK_ENV=development
```

and getting this error:

```
Building users
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.6.7-alpine
 ---> cb04a359db13
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06bb39a49444
Step 3/6 : COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
ERROR: Service 'users' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder353668631/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

I don't even know where to start with debugging this. When I tried to access the directory it gave me permission error. So I tried to run the command with sudo which didn't help. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is there a `requirements.txt` in your `./services/users` directory?

Comment: @larks  Omg ... I moved the file to users and it worked. I thought it was meant to be in the directory I'm executing the script from. Can't believe I was stuck on this trivial error for so long.

Comment: So the requirements file needs to be in the same directory as where the context attribute points to.

Comment: @BillyDarwin well that's the full point of the context, if you do specify a context, then yes, the files are relative to it. If you don't have a context, then the context is relative to the `Dockerfile` location. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Comment: And if you are not using `docker-compose` but build the image via `docker build` then the context is this only parameter you can give to the build command `docker build . # context is the current dir` vs `docker build /path/to/my/context`

Answer (score 0):

Little late to reply, but second COPY command `COPY . /usr/src/app` replaces the /usr/src/app content generated by `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.

Try

```sh
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install in temp directory
RUN mkdir /dependencies

COPY ./requirements.txt /dependencies/requirements.txt
RUN cd /dependencies && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

# copy generated dependencies
RUN cp -r /dependencies/* /usr/src/app/

CMD python3 manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This would only be an issue with pip installed files in the current directory, and the OP had those same files in their build context. A copy command does not delete files, and I believe pip will install to user or system directories rather than the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem building an image with beryllium, and I solved this deleting it into the .dockerignore

```
$ sudo docker build -t apache .
```

Sending build context to Docker daemon

```
10.55MB Step 1/4 : FROM centos  ---> 9f38484d220f Step 2/4 :

RUN yum install httpd -y 

---> Using cache  ---> ccdafc4ae476 Step 3/4 : 

**COPY ./**beryllium** /var/www/html COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder04301**
```

$nano .dockerignore

```
startbootstrap-freelancer-master

run.sh

pro

fruit

beryllium

Bell.zip
```

**remove** beryllium from that file

---

```
$ sudo docker build -t apache .
```

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.92MB

Step 1/4 : FROM centos

 ---> 9f38484d220f

Step 2/4 : RUN yum install httpd -y

 ---> Using cache

 ---> ccdafc4ae476

Step 3/4 : COPY ./beryllium /var/www/HTML

 ---> 40ebc02992a9

Step 4/4 : CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND

 ---> Running in dab0a406c89e

Removing intermediate container dab0a406c89e

 ---> 1bea741cfb65

Successfully built 1bea741cfb65

Successfully tagged apache:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

As [larsks suggests in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288753/copy-command-fails#comment97307109_55288753), you need the file in the `services/users` directory. To understand why, an understanding of the "context" is useful.

Docker does not build on the client, it does not see your current directory, or other files on your filesystem. Instead, the last argument to the build command is passed as the build context. With docker-compose, this context defaults to the current directory, which you will often see as `.` in a `docker build` command, but you can override that as you've done here with `./services/users` as your context. When you run a build, the very first step is to send that build context from the docker client to the server. Even when the client and server are on the same host (a common default, especially for desktop environments), this same process happens. Files listed in `.dockerignore`, and files in parent directories to the build context are not sent to the docker server.

When you run a `COPY` or `ADD` command, the first argument (or all but the last argument when you have multiple) refer to files from the build context, and the last argument is the destination file or directory inside the image.

---

Therefore, when you put together this compose file entry:

```
build:
  context: ./services/users
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
```

with this COPY command:

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
```

the COPY will try to copy the `requirements.txt` file from the build context generated from `./services/users`, meaning `./services/users/requirements.txt` needs to exist, and not be excluded by a `.dockerignore` file in `./services/users`.